# Pass data back from DetailedView of UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, detailsview

I have a UITextView in a DetailedView of my UITableView. I want to be able to add some text, which is sent to a webservice with POST. If text is added it needs to show an indicator for that cell in the UITableView.

When the POST is sent and viewWillDisapear I set the UITextView to empty.

So my question is if also request that comment before the detailedView disapears and pass it back to the UITableView class?

And how can I pass back the data when the detailedView disapears?

Or do request the to see if there is a comment from the UITableView class? And then also pass it in to display it from didSelectRowForIndexPath.

Basically I display some data already in the DetailedView which is passed from the UITableView class. And now wont to set some new data in the detailedView which will be displayed in the same view different for each view, and show an indicator image on that cell in the UITableView if there is a comment.

I realize it´s a bit vague question but give it shoot, perhaps somebody can point me in the right direction with som reference to a tutorial for passing data back and forth off a cell and it´s detailedView.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you pushing your view controllers to a `UINavigationController`? If so, you can use the navigation controller to access the parent view controller and pass data that way.

Comment: @pgb Yes I pass it like this: 
`[self.detailViewController initWithDetailsSelected:childrensDictionary:group:startTime:endTime];`
                                                                               
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];`

Comment: You can create a global variable using  external in a header then add the header whenever you want to access the variable

Comment: Global variables are BAD! God will kill a kitten if you do this. Be warned.

Comment: @pgb Ok how to access the parentViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing data between view controllers is best achieved by using delegates.

See this article on protocols and delegates.... [**tutorial**](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

Comment: Ok I will have a look at that.

Comment: So in my case it would be both the UIViewControllers that registers for the protocol? Or will it only be the one that needs to be informed?

Comment: The one that need to be informed IMPLEMENTS the protocol so...@interface MyViewC : UIViewController<MyProtocol>

Comment: and the child view controller has a property id<MyProtocol> delegate... etc etc

Comment: Ok thanks works great. I now pass back a BOOL in this way. But how can determine which row in the TableView the detailedView returned from? I want the set an image based on this BOOL. Any suggestion?